# Discount is being added to a quote line even when there is no discount schedule or manual discount CPQ

Tags: community, quote, cpq, quotelineitem, cpq-plugins

I have a quote line where the user enters the subscription term(month) as follows.
When user saves the quote line an additional discount of 10% is added automatically even when there is no discount schedule at all and the sales rep has not added a manual discount either. Any idea on what could be causing this?

[image: Quote line]

[image: Discount added]

[image: Quote line history]

Answer (score 0):

Those are possible reasons

> 1. Custom Script (Quote Calculator Plugin) basing on Quote fields
> 2. Price Rules
> 3. Quote Trigger

Answer (score 0):

It does appear that it's a discount schedule, but not a product-level one. It could be associated to the product option, or a contracted price on the quoted account (or an account higher in its hierarchy).